# Запятая или тире

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой знак лучше в этом предложении. 
Ваша жена() она принимает участие в управлении?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше поставить тире: Ваша жена - она принимает участие в управлении?

Это оформление с именительным темы.

Comment: Благодарю.

Answer (score 3):

Розенталь считает, что лучше запятая:

После именительного темы в сегментированных конструкциях, за которыми следует личное местоимение, чаще ставится запятая:

*А трамвай, он как идёт?*

*Гречневая каша, она не быстро варится.*

*Овчарки, они бывают красивые.*

Такая пунктуация сохраняется и в тех случаях, когда в позиции именительного темы (сегмента) выступают другиe грамматические структуры — словосочетание, прилагательное, предложно-падежное сочетание:

*Русский старинный фарфор, он очень сейчас вот ценится.*

*Зелёная, она разве не в чистке?* (о кофте).

*А на семнадцати камнях, они чем лучше?* (о часах).

Comment: А интонация первой части в вопросительных предложениях какая? Также присоединительный союз какую роль играет? (Без него предложение неясно выглядит и непонятно как читается).

Comment: Вопросительное без союза: Зеленая, она разве не в чистке? Розенталь пишет: "чаще ставится запятая", то есть не отрицает возможность тире. А вообще после именительного темы может стоять как тире, так и запятая.

Answer (score 0):

Еще подобный пример у Розенталя. ***Площадь Ленина/ не подскажите где?*** Заметье, вопрос какой знак препинания нужен после слэша, остается открытом.

Comment: Здесь по ситуации - тире. И вопрос неожиданный и пауза нужна для лучшего осмысления спрашиваемым.

Answer (score 0):

Тут зависит от интонации, с которой произносится. И, возможно, от контекста.
Если вопрос про жену предполагает неожиданный переход к этой теме (о жене раньше не ничего говорилось и не подразумевалось), то оформление с тире естественно. То же и с трамваем и прочими примерами у Розенталя.

Если же жена, трамвай или каша - естественные в разговоре объекты, не несут неожиданного поворота разговора, то я соглашусь с Розенталем.