# Знак препинания в выражении "Коля он такой"

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, какой нужен знак препинания в выражении "Коля он такой!"... в значении "Даааа, он такой!"

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, *Коля* - именительный темы, а все предложение должно выглядеть так:

**Коля — он такой!**

*Однако при именительном темы, более тесно связанном с основным предложением, в котором имеется личное или указательное местоимение в качестве слова-отсылки, ставится тире: Тягач — он как танк, только без башни (газ.); Марченко — тот был человек, золотой человек (Каз.); Дорога в дождь — она не сладость, дорога в дождь — она беда (Евт.).*
[ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ ПРИ ИМЕНИТЕЛЬНОМ ТЕМЫ](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110)

См. также: [Запятая или тире](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40690/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5/40699#40699)

Вариант **Коля, он такой!** я убрал, так как его можно спутать с обращением.